# Why gives FactoryGirl such large ID's in my testcases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am using a Rails 2.3.x and Ruby 1.8.7 environment with FactoryGirl 1.3.3 (edit: version of FG has no influence as far as I can see)

In my console, when I do:

```
Factory(:user_activity)
```

I get:

```
#<UserActivity id: 25, user_id: 1, resource_id: nil, ... >
```

However when I do in my testcase:

```
@ua = Factory(:user_activity)
```

I get:

```
#<UserActivity id: 980190963, user_id: 298486374, resource_id: nil,  ... >
```

Where are these large IDs coming from? How can I setup my testcases to use the expected IDs as seen in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the IDs are calculated in the same or an equivalent way as when using ActiveRecord fixtures (AR fixtures hashes the fixture label).

I don't know why using Factory in console will give you more normal IDs however.

Do you really need to know the ID in order to test? Or can you use your `@ua` variable to get the ID if you need it?